# Como mostrar otra pagina en google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Tengo poca experiencia usando HtmlService de GAS, logre correr algunos js en la pagina que cargo de inicio, pero deseo que deje de mostrar la primer pagina y que al consumir una nueva pagina me la muestre con los parámetros que le envió a una función.

El función es:

```
function showPagina(iSession){
  var principal = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pPrincipal')
  principal.data = iSession;
  return principal.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Sistemas | Control de Activos')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setFaviconUrl(sFavIcon);
    
}
```

Pero al consumirla me regresa el siguiente mensaje en la consola de chrome:
[image: Error]

Comment: Ayuda!! mencionen si formule mal mi pregunta.. o necesitan mas información. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El código no está completo. Deberías incluir la función doGet(e). Para más detalles, revisa [mcve].

Comment: Si lo uso pero para mostrar una pantalla de Login... este vendría siendo un segundo html donde tengo algunas acciones del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Las aplicaciones web creadas con Google Apps Script pueden crear y servir HTML, para ello cargan un estructura principal y luego sobre esta se puede actualizar el contenido inicial tomando contenido estático de otros archivos en formato HTML, generarlo de forma dinámica mediante plantillas, directamente mediante programación o la combinación de lo anterior.

## Ejemplo usando archivos estáticos

El siguiente código corresponde a una aplicación web realizada con Google Apps Script y HtmlService. Esta aplicación al ser cargada muestra un contenido predeterminado. Consta de dos botones, los cuales actualizan el contenido de un `DIV`.

Consta de cuatro archivos, uno en formato `.gs` y tres en formato `.html`.

### Código.gs

Incluye el código que corre del lado del servidor. La función doGet() es la función principal la cual devuelve el contenido de la página Index.html. Las funciones getPagina1 y getPagina2 toman el contenido de los archivos Pagina1.html y Pagina2.html y lo devuelven como un objeto de contenido.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getPagina1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina1').getContent();
  return html
}

function getPagina2() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pagina2').getContent();
  return html
}
```

### Index.html

Contenido HTML principal. Incluye la estructura principal y dos botones los cuales actualizan el contenido del DIV con `resultado` como id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function actualizarDiv(html, button) {
        var div = document.getElementById('resultado');
        div.innerHTML = html;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Página 1"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
          .withUserObject(this)
          .getPagina1()" />
    <input type="button" value="Página 2"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
          .withUserObject(this)
          .getPagina2()" />
     <div id="resultado">
     Contenido predeterminado
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Pagina1.html

```
<font color="brown">Contenido de pagina 1</font>
```

### Pagina2.html

```
<font color="blue">Contenido de pagina 2</font>
```

## Referencias

- [Types of Scripts > Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: excelente explicación andaba un poco perdido, te agradezco el tiempo que invertiste en tu respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

para este caso yo uso un metodo un poco mas eficiente, (a mi parecer), el cual consiste en usar una funcion unica para llamar cualquier página .html del GAS.

```
function incluir(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
         .getContent();
}
```

Luego en el Index.html pones algo asi:

```
  <button onclick="requestcodegs('registro')">
    Registrarse
  </button>
```

y dentro del script del html una función. en este caso

> requestcodegs();

que llame nuestro incluir de esta manera:

```
function requestcodegs(entrada) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cargacodegs).incluir(entrada);
}

function cargacodegs(entrada) {
   document.getElementById('general').innerHTML=entrada; 
}
```

Al hacer esto, podremos llamar cuantas veces queramos la función:

> requestcodegs("nombredelapagina");

Y luego, el contenido lo pondremos con un

> inner.HTML

en un div o contenedor de preferencia.

[Aqui encontraras un ejemplo.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzD-IYLH_txkBf7K9p7wP9SZi-wu13OCzbUJ5PytDOTKQj78llU/exec)

[image: Como ves mi index.html está vacío, ya que depende de una validación si se muestra inicio, o el perfil del usuario]

Como ves mi index.html está vacío, ya que depende de una validación si se muestra inicio, o el perfil del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que la pregunta es de hace unos meses pero creo que es interesante.

La función doGet, cómo doPost, recibe consultas a través de la URL del tipo:

> direccion.es/page?parámetro=valor&otroParámetro=otroValor...puedes añadir más...

Vamos a responder a un parámetro para cargar dinámicamente una página por defecto, la principal, y otra más:

**Archivo Código.gs**

```
1- var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
2- function doGet(e) {
3-   var page = e.parameter.p || "Web";
4-   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
5- }
```

1. Ruta de la página web para utilizarla más adelante.
2. La función doGet recibe parámetros (e)
3. He utilizado la letra 'p' (e.parameter.**p**) para pasar el valor de la página que quiero cargar a la variable 'page'. Verás cómo un poco más adelante en las páginas html. He utilizado '||' para indicar que en el caso de no existir
   parámetro 'p' pase 'Web' a la variable (page). 'Web' es el nombre de la página principal.
4. doGet devuelve la página pasada a través del parámetro 'p' como una plantilla html.

**Web.html (página principal por defecto)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Página principal</h1>
    <p>Dale: <a href="<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=Alumno' ?>">Página Alumno</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

El atributo HREF del enlace es un Scriptlet que concatena la ruta de la web que guardamos como variable (rutaWeb) con el parámetro 'p' y su valor 'Alumno' que es el nombre de otra página, a la que lleva el enlace.

**Alumno.html (la otra página)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Alumnos</h1>
    <p>Puedes volver a la página <a href="<?!= rutaWeb ?>">Principal</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Fíjate que para volver a la página principal no incluimos parámetro alguno, recuerda en (Código.gs) la construcción de la variable 'page'.

[Puedes probar el funcionamiento.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8h5htzGfne2LrlDfcgaLP93cN6loD6udRlGx-ZWM/dev)

[Proyecto funcionando compartido.](https://script.google.com/d/1QWms1TTobndrUeM607PKmCPwwCAnwNaJ-bDgnTzHWBxj2ZEgMR-DYUhS/edit?usp=sharing)