# Incluir Script asociado a un formulario google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto 
 con dos formularios en un mismo spreadsheet, todo el código funciono bien hasta que seguí las recomendaciones mostradas en [una de las respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81505/51750) a [Como mostrar otra pagina en google apps script?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/61006/51750)

Una vez que hice eso ya no me sirvió el código script de los formularios para cargar datos en el mismo form... que entre otras cosas podía:

```
//Mostrar la fecha y hora en el form
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById("mtempo").innerHTML = n; 
//Cargar el campo fecha, con la fecha actual
 document.getElementById('fecent').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
//Cargar un select con los datos del spreadsheet
  $(function () {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildNumcon)
       .getListOptions();
  });
```

Una de las soluciones que encontre implicab incluir desde el index

```
 <?!= include('ScriptForm1'); ?>
```

Pero esto se cargaba antes de llamar el formulario así que no me sirvió, investigando encontré que podía llamar el script desde el botón que llama al formulario.

```
<button onclick="solicitarFormulario('Form1');solicitarScript('ScriptForm1')">Formulario
 1</button>
```

y en el script del index que si funciona bien llamar al archivo:

```
function solicitarScript(scriptForm){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(importarScript).include(scriptForm);
 }
 function importarScript(scriptForm){
   $.getScript(scriptForm);
 }
```

Hasta aquí todo esta "bien" logro llamar al script pero se sigue cargando antes que el formulario y no parece tener ninguna comunicación con los elementos de este!!! Aunque dice que si no llena ninguno de los datos y las funciones que antes funcionaban como limpiarFormulario() al cancelar dice que no esta definida.

¿Alguien que me explique como a un niño de 5 años que fue lo que paso?

---

Estoy usando jQuery y todo lo que me sirva. Separe los códigos para tratar que funcionara.

## Main.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate() 
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function incluir(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
   .getContent();
}

function getListOptions() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets...')
  .getSheetByName("Parametros");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+4);//4 en vez de lastRow(Quitar espacios en blanco)
  var conductor = myRange.getValues(); 
  return( conductor );
}

function processFormEntregas(e){
 //Guardar imagen en Drive
  var name='Entregas';
  var carpeta = DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFolders("title contains '"+name+"'");
  if (carpeta.hasNext()===true) {    
      while (carpeta.hasNext()) {
      var folder = carpeta.next();
      Logger.log(folder.getName()+' '+folder.getId());
      }
  }else{
    var folder=DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name);
  }
  //Crea el archivo en la carpeta 'name'
  var blob = e.imginp.getBlob();
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);
  var fileId = file.getId();

  var sMtempo = new Date();
  var sNroref = e.nroref;
  ...
  var sImginp = ("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+fileId);  

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...');
  var hojaDatos = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Entregas'); 
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,1).setValue(sMtempo);
  ...
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,8).setFormula('IMAGE("'+sImginp+'";1)');

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  print("Su registro ha sido guardado con exito."); //Esperando para probar
}
```

## Index.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

//De arriba no se que sirve y que no, prefiero que sobre que falte
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Scindex'); ?>       
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
    <p align="left" >
    <button onclick="solicitarFormulario('Frecogidas')">Recogidas</button>
    <button onclick="solicitarFormulario('Fentregas');solicitarScript('Scentregas')">Entregas</button>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="Principal" class="smn47">

   </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

## Scindex.html:

```
<script>
 function solicitarFormulario(entrada) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cargarFormulario).incluir(entrada);
 }
 function cargarFormulario(entrada) {
  document.getElementById('Principal').innerHTML=entrada; 
 }
 function solicitarScript(scentrada){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(importarScript).incluir(scentrada);
 }
 function importarScript(scentrada){
  $.getScript(scentrada);
 }
 //Esta función estaba originalmente en el form Entregas, al hacer el
 //cambio como no funcionaba he probado desde aqui y lo llama pero no he 
 //declarado bien el formulario porque me dice que no puede realizar reset 
 //de undefined
function limpiarFormulario() {
      var activeForm = this.form;
      activeForm.reset();
      activeForm.getElementById('fecent').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
      activeForm.getElementById('output').src=" ";
      activeForm.getElementById('output').alt="Vista Previa";
     }     
</script>
```

## Fentregas.html:

```
<div >
  <form id="Entregas" name="Entregas" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <p id="mtempo" name="mtempo" align="right"></p>
    <br> Referencias:
    <br> <input type="text" name="nroref" id="nroref" placeholder="Referencia(s) recogida(s)" />
    ...
    <br><br>
    <input class="action" type="button" value="GUARDAR" onclick="procesaFormulario()">
    <input class="create" type="button" value="CANCELAR" onclick="limpiarFormulario()">
   </form>
  </div>
```

## Scentregas.html:

```
<script>
 //Esta seccion de código estaba independiente en el formulario, se activaba 
 //sola cuando lo cargaba ahora no se como llamar al evento para que cargue 
 //luego de los elementos del formulario
  var activeForm =document.forms['Entregas'];
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleString();
  this.form.elements['mtempo'].innerHTML = n;       
  activeForm.getElementById('fecent').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);

  $(function () {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildNumcon)
       .getListOptions();
      });

 function buildNumcon(conductor) {
  var list = $('#numcon');
  list.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < conductor.length; i++) {
   list.append(new Option(conductor[i],conductor[i]));
  }
 }

 var loadFile = function(event) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(){
       var output = activeForm.getElementById('output');
       output.src = reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
     };

//Esto ni siquiera lo he probado
 function procesaFormulario(){ google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(limpiarFormulario(this)).processFormEntregas(document.forms[0]);
 }  
</script>
```

Aun estoy viendo como puedo llamar a los elementos del formulario como lo hacia antes con document.getElementById no funciona

---

Lo del Include/incluir ya esta corregido a las librerias jquery no les habia hecho mucho caso, las tenia asi desde el principio casi y no me habian dado problemas y aunq encontre  como declarar los input para limpiarformulario()

```
function limpiarFormulario() {
  var actFrm = document.forms[0];
  for (i = 0; i < actFrm.elements.length; i++)
  {
    field_type = actFrm.elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
    switch (field_type)
    {
     case "text":
     case "password":
     case "textarea":
     case "hidden":
      actFrm.elements[i].value = "";
      break;
     case "radio":
     case "checkbox":
      if (actFrm.elements[i].checked){
       actFrm.elements[i].checked = false;
      }
      break;
     case "select-one":
     case "select-multi":
      actFrm.elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
      break;
     case "date":
      actFrm.elements[i].value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
     default:
      break;
    }
   }
  }
```

aun no he podido resolver lo demas.... necesito crear una function que se active despues de cargar el formulario :(

---

Me disculpo primero por EL DESASTRE DE MIS POST, he estado bajo mucho estrés por este código y le he dado tantas vueltas que he tenido que dedicarme a "limpiarlo" para aclarar mis ideas...

En efecto seguí las recomendaciones que me hicieron y las sume a algunas modificaciones propias:

1) cambie la forma en que se usan los botones para llamar los formularios, en vez de usar el onclick usando:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(Bentregas).click(function(){
   solicitarFormulario('Fentregas');
  });
 });
```

El problema sigue siendo LA LLAMADA DEL SCRIPT!!! No puedo usar:

```
<?!= include('ScriptForm1'); ?>
```

Por que llama el script antes de que se cargue el formulario y no encuentro como crear una funcion que se ejecute una vez que ese formulario sea descargado....

y la opcion de `$.getScript(scriptForm);`

me esta dando el siguiente error:

> accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=http…BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192:1
>   GET
>   ...//accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&conti…%2BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192
>
> userCodeAppPanel:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   ...//accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&conti…%2BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://n-g53co5wg4hrumzlg4qlbmekx5pxsqh6kushamzq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   400.

---

Aquí la solución a esta pregunta: [Como incluir un scrip en programación modular con GAS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90837/como-incluir-un-scrip-en-programaci%C3%B3n-modular-con-gas/90893#90893)

Comment: Estas usand jQuery ¿verdad? ¿Cada formulario está en archivos HTML distintos o están en el mismo archivo? Crea un [mcve] e incluye tanto el código del archivo .gs como de los archivos .html

Comment: He pasado a la pregunta el contenido de lo que publicaste como respuesta con unos pequeños ajustes. Cuando tengas oportunidad, revisa la publicación y si lo consideras pertinente reordena el contenido pensando en alguien que lee la pregunta por primera vez y en ti misma leyéndola dentro de unas semanas o meses.

Comment: En la vista de "activas" veo que el hilo fue modificado hace dos días pero no veo la modificación. Es posible que la edición haya sido en una respuesta y esta haya sido eliminada por no ser una respuesta. Responde a este comentario usando una arroba respuesta si aún requieres ayuda. Material de apoyo [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65)

Comment: @Rubén aun requiero la ayuda, realice las modificaciones que me sugirieron y algunas mas que me parecieron oportunas....

Comment: Si aún requires ayuda, te sugiero hacer nuevas preguntas, pero más específicas. En un principio te parecerá más trabajo pero te va a redituar mucho.

Comment: No se si leíste mi comentario previo, si así fue, por nuevas preguntas me refería a [una nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) no a agregar más contenido al final de la ya publicada. Como tu misma has reconocido, la publicación se ha vuelto muy larga y complicada. Si no lo has hecho aún, lee [mcve]. Si tienes dudas sobre dicho artículo, dinos cuál es tu duda haciendo clic en "añade un comentario" (se encuentra abajo de este comentario)

Comment: Voy a tomarme el atrevimiento de publicar la solución a mi problema (o al menos la que yo encontre) por si alguien mas llega a tener el mismo problema. En vista de la necesidad de separar los códigos la solución mas util para aprovechar la instrucción google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cargarFormulario).incluir(entrada); fue crear una función cargarValores() para llenar los campos de fecha y select con los datos que necesitaba y hacer el llamado a esta función desde el onfocus del primer campo de mi formulario, quizás no fue la mas optima pero me sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

## Resumen

El código en la pregunta tiene varios problemas

1. Problema con nombres de funciones
2. Cargar varias veces jQuery, siendo estas versiones distintas
3. Función limpiarFormularios
4. Orden de ejecución de funciones

Quizás otros.

## Explicación

#### 1. Problema con nombres de funciones

Un problema que tiene el código es que en el archivo `.gs` la función se llama `incluir()` pero en el archivo `Index.html` no se llama a esta función sino a `include`. La línea en cuestión es:

```
<?!= include('Scindex'); ?>
```

#### 2. Cargar varias veces jQuery

Otro problema es que `Index.html` está cargando varias veces jQuery pero usando versiones y alojamientos distintos. Las líneas son las siguientes:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Me parece que no es demasiado grave mientras las propiedades se llamen igual, la que prevalecerá será la última en ser cargada, sin embargo, por un lado tu aplicación está requiriendo más tiempo del necesario en cargarse y podría ser que tu código requiera una características que haya sido cambiada.

La recomendación es que dediques algo de tiempo a entender jQuery, escojas una versión y sólo uses una en cada aplicación para prevenir interferencias y facilitar el depuración del código y en particular el desempeño de tu aplicación.

#### 3. Problema con función limpiarformularios

Reportado como resuelto por el OP en una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/87855/65) quedando la función de la siguiente forma

```
function limpiarFormulario() {
  var actFrm = document.forms[0];
  for (i = 0; i < actFrm.elements.length; i++)
  {
    field_type = actFrm.elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
    switch (field_type)
    {
     case "text":
     case "password":
     case "textarea":
     case "hidden":
      actFrm.elements[i].value = "";
      break;
     case "radio":
     case "checkbox":
      if (actFrm.elements[i].checked){
       actFrm.elements[i].checked = false;
      }
      break;
     case "select-one":
     case "select-multi":
      actFrm.elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
      break;
     case "date":
      actFrm.elements[i].value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
     default:
      break;
    }
   }
  }
```

#### 4. Orden de ejecución de funciones

Las llamadas a funciones del lado del servidor se realiza de forma asíncrona, esto quiere decir, que se realiza la llamada, y se continua ejecutando el resto del código, sin esperar que que termine de ejecutarse la función del lado del servidor.

Podríamos decir que el problema está en la siguiente línea de código

```
<button onclick="solicitarFormulario('Fentregas');solicitarScript('Scentregas')">Entregas</button>
```

y en

```
function solicitarFormulario(entrada) {
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cargarFormulario).incluir(entrada);
}
function cargarFormulario(entrada) {
 document.getElementById('Principal').innerHTML=entrada; 
}
function solicitarScript(scentrada){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(importarScript).incluir(scentrada);
}
function importarScript(scentrada){
 $.getScript(scentrada);
}
```

Una forma de solucionar esto cambiar el lugar donde llamas a la segunda función. En lugar de hacerlo en el botón, hacer en la función cargarFormulario.

El botón quedaría así:

```
<button onclick="solicitarFormulario('Fentregas');">Entregas</button>
```

y la otra parte del código así:

```
function solicitarFormulario(entrada) {
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cargarFormulario).incluir(entrada);
}
function cargarFormulario(entrada) {
 document.getElementById('Principal').innerHTML=entrada;
 solicitarScript('Scentregas');
}
function solicitarScript(scentrada){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(importarScript).incluir(scentrada);
}
function importarScript(scentrada){
 $.getScript(scentrada);
}
```