# Como incluir un scrip en programación modular con GAS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Como puedo llamar al script de mi formulario desde index o el script del index para que me cargue los valores predefinidos para los campos del formulario?
La opción,

```
<?!= incluir('scriptform'); ?>
```

que se coloca en html llama el script antes de que se cargue el formulario y no encuentro como crear una funcion que se ejecute una vez que ese formulario sea descargado....

y la opcion:

```
$.getScript(scriptForm);
```

me esta dando el siguiente error:

> accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=http…BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192:1
>   GET
>   ...//accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&conti…%2BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192
>
> userCodeAppPanel:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   ...//accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&conti…%2BDate().toISOString().substring(0,%2B10);%2B%257D%2B%26_%3D1501010636192.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://n-g53co5wg4hrumzlg4qlbmekx5pxsqh6kushamzq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   400.

Comment: Este parece ser un Problema XY. Estás tratando de resolver el problema X, en este caso, cargar los valores predefinidos para los campos del formulario, y tu piensas que la solución Y, en este caso el uso de plantillas podría funcionar pero en lugar de preguntar acerca de X, estás preguntando acerca de Y. ¿Los valores predefinidos son fijos o los cargas de algún lado? Si los cargas, indica si los obtienes de una hoja de cálculo o de de otra parte.

Comment: Los "valores predefinidos" por no encontrar otra forma de llamarlos, los obtengo de un spreadsheet, en este caso especifico para llenar un select.

Comment: Y una vez que se muestre el formulario ¿A donde vas a enviar los datos que recopiles con este? ¿También a una hoja de cálculo?

Comment: Si, recuerda que estoy trabajando con modulos. Tengo un Index desde donde llamo a mi formulario1 y mi formulario2

Comment: En este sitio, si bien es válido hacer preguntas de seguimiento, cada una debe tratarse de forma independiente, por otro lado, para facilitar las cosas, vamos a enfocarnos en un problema a la vez. Al igual que en la pregunta anterior, te sugiero hacer un [mcve]. Para darte una mejor idea de a que nos referimos con ello en un caso como el tuyo, he puesto uno a manera de respuesta.

Comment: En realidad no estoy hablando de un problema diferente es una sola pregunta que aun no consigo responder, la solucion que me das no me sirve porque estoy trabajando con modulos (tuve que separar los scripts de mis fomularios de sus html) que como explique debo llamar preferiblemente despues de que se cargue el html de mi formulario para poder cargar la informacion del select que a su vez esta en un spreadsheet, sin los modulos todo funciona pero con ellos solo me muestra el select vacio

Comment: Aquí cuando hablamos de preguntas, nos referimos a preguntas publicadas, así que aún y cuando se trate del mismo problema, al momento tienes dos preguntas publicadas. Cada una debe ser autocontenida, es decir, cada pregunta debe incluir la información mínima necesaria sobre un problema específico. Cuando las preguntas abarcan varios problemas, es posible que sean cerradas por demasiado amplias. En el caso de esta pregunta, mencionas dos formas que pensabas que podían ser la solución, eso está bien, sin embargo falta el [mcve]...

Comment: De todas formas teniendo oportunidad modificaré mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente lo que el OP llama "programación modular" se refiere a lo que en la documentación de Google Apps Script se describe como [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) y en particular a "[Force printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)".

Al inicio de [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) se menciona

> If you paste the example below into the script editor, the contents of the `<?= ... ?>` tag (a [printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)) will appear in italics. That italicized code runs on the server *before the page is served to the user*. Because scriptlet code executes before the page is served, it can only run once per page; unlike client-side JavaScript or Apps Script functions that you call through [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication), scriptlets can't execute again after the page loads.

**Traducción**  (énfasis mío)

> Si pegas el siguiente ejemplo en el editor de scripts, el contenido de la etiqueta `<?=...?>` (un "printing scriptlet") se mostrará en itálicas. Ese código italizado se ejecuta en el servidor ***antes que la página sea servida al usuario***. Debido a que el código scriptlet se ejecutar antes de que la página es servida, esta únicamente puede ejecutarse una vez por página; contrario a las funciones del lado del cliente de JavaScript o Apps Script que puedes llamar mediante google.script.run, los scriptlets no se pueden ejecutar de nuevo luego de que la página se carga.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World! The time is <?= new Date() ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

El siguiente código corresponde a una muy pequeña aplicación web realizada en Google Apps Script usando plantillas.

Muestra una lista desplegable (select) y al hacer clic en el botón "Submit" agrega un mensaje indicando la opción seleccionada.

Las opciones del select se preparan en el código del lado del servidor (archivo Código.gs) y son pasadas al lado del cliente mediante luego de generar el código HTML.

Se incluye la función procesarFormulario para mostrar cómo se podría llamar una función del lado del servidor para hacer algo con los datos recopilados con el formulario y mostrar el resultado del lado del cliente.

#### Código.gs

```
function doGet() {
  // Cargar plantilla del lado servidor
  var plantilla = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  //Crear la lista de opciones
  var opciones = '<option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>\n';
  opciones += '<option value="Fresa">Fresa</option>\n';
  opciones += '<option value="Vainilla">Vainilla</option>\n';
  //Agregar opciones a la plantilla
  plantilla.opciones = opciones;
  // Generar html a partir de la plantilla
  var html = plantilla.evaluate(); 
  // Enviar plantilla al lado del cliente
  return html;

}

function procesarFormulario(objetoFormulario) {
  //Hacer algo con el objeto formulario
  var salida = objetoFormulario.sabor;
  return salida;
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Previene el envío del formulario
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(objetoFormulario) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(actualizarOpcion).procesarFormulario(objetoFormulario);
      }
      function actualizarOpcion(opcion) {
        var div = document.getElementById('salida');
        div.innerHTML = 'El sabor seleccionado fue ' + opcion;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="miFormulario" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <select name="sabor" id="id">
      <?!= opciones ?>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="salida"></div>
 </body>
```